# Redirecting to login page after Session Expired in Spring

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

1 I am facing a problem. I have 3 role in my project user,admin,expert.
2 3 different login page for different user.
3 What I have want is when ever the session is expired,and after that if User did any event the page should direct to according to there role.
e.g User should get redirect to User login and Admin to admin a login.

I have read many document about it.Some has give idea of adding filter and check the session in filter.
But the issue with that is I did not get the role in filter.'
So Do SpringSecurityHolder will work inside Filter.

I have also read about the ApplicationListerner which take Event.
I have return the code but I dont know how to direct from inside the listerner class

```
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationListener;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContext;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionDestroyedEvent;

public class SessionTimeoutHandler  implements ApplicationListener<HttpSessionDestroyedEvent>{

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(HttpSessionDestroyedEvent event) {

        List<SecurityContext> lstSecurityContext = event
                .getSecurityContexts();

        for (SecurityContext securityContext : lstSecurityContext)
        {
            Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();

            List<GrantedAuthority> authList = (List<GrantedAuthority>) authentication
                    .getAuthorities();
            String userRole = authList.get(0).getAuthority();

            if(userRole.equals("ROLE_ADMIN")){


            }else if(userRole.equals("ROLE_EXPERT")){

            }else{

            }

        }

    }

}
```

Please help me out How will I will be able to redirect the page.

Thanks for the help

Comment: So I deleted my answer, and as far as I know and understand, it wont, as you in you are code are getting authentication which is not there as the user has logged out. Please read a few basics, they will be helpful.

Comment: But Do you think there must be some functionality from which we can decide where to redirect the page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There really isn't a good way to determine what role the user is in once the HTTP session expires because once it expires the user information is gone.

You cannot do a redirect from a ApplicationListener because a session may expire when the users browser is not making a request (we cannot push information to the browser unless there is a connection open).

The best solution I can give you is to set a cookie that indicates which role the user is in. The cookie would outlive the session and then you can perform a redirect to the appropriate log in page based on the cookie.

Of course this fails if multiple different types of users are using the same computer because they share the same cookies.

Comment: I way I was thinking is by writing Exception handler on Controller based and to redirect if it get that Session Exception.

Comment: The session expiration happens in the background, so there is no reference to an HttpServletResponse to send a redirect.

Comment: I am saving some Value in Session.e.g UserName in Session.
So If the User will not do activity more then 10 min.The Session will get timeout.So the UserName value will also get destroyed.So I can check that in my Controller.
Dont you think it will work.
My Controller Mapped with   Different for Different user . For Admin it is mapped with /admin/.
Put Some light on it.

Comment: You only get access to the HttpServletResponse (how a response is sent to a browser) when the web browser makes a request. However, the session times out when there is no request being made by the browser. This means that the controller will not be able to do anything when the session expires. More fundamentally, you cannot send information back to the browser when the session expires.